# R Replace Repeat Loop

Tags: r, performance, loops, vectorization, repeat

I'm writing a function to play a game many times and record the median number of steps required to win the game, and applying this function over a list of game sizes. It works fairly well for small sizes (<100), but takes an impracticably long time for larger games. I'm fairly certain that this is because the code to play the game itself is a loop.

I'm pretty new to this, but I imagine that the way to improve the performance of the code would be to replace the repeat loop with some kind of vectorized function. Does anybody have any suggestion as to how I could do this?

```
plays <- function(c){
  outcomes <- replicate(10000,{
  # the list of results from 10,000 'plays' of the game size c
    bag <- c(1:c) 
    # an object containing the elements that are being played
    obj <- c(1:c)
    # an object with the indices of the elements of bag
    counter <- 0 
    # an object that counts the number of iterations 
    repeat{
      if(length(unique(bag))==1){
      # check to see if all objects in bag are identical
        break
        # then end the loop
      }
      # otherwise make one randomly selected object
      # in bag like another randomly selected object in bag
      k <- sample(obj,1,replace=F)
      l <- sample(obj[-k],1,replace=F)
      bag[l] <- bag[k]
      counter <- counter+1
      # and add 1 to the counter
    }
    counter 
    # output the number of steps to reach the end of the game 
  })
  median(outcomes)
  # output the median number of steps
}
```

Comment: Hoe big can the `c` be?

Comment: I would be tempted to reduce your 10,000 figure for starters, and to capture a vector of actual values of `outcomes` rather than just the median.  You can probably make a reasonable estimate of the median from a much smaller set, especially if you can see the distribution.

Comment: I don't think other coding will help much, because fundamentally it is about the game algorithm that makes it it slow. Expanding on @Andrew Gustar's comment: Use the captured smaller set to, say, plot a simple scatter chart to see the relationship between `c` and `counter`.

Comment: Running `microbenchmark` on this for a few small values of c suggests that the time increases ~c-squared, so even if you can speed up the loop, large values are always going to be relatively much tougher.

Comment: @d.b I'm trying to run a simulation for a c of 1000, which still hadn't completed after 20ish hours.

Comment: @epi99 What you are suggesting is almost exactly what I did: I simulated for c between 3 and 100, and modeled the results. I'm simulating 1000 because I want to evaluate if the model maintains its accuracy for domain values well outside of that range.

Comment: As others have mentioned, the code is not slow because of loop. It's due to the amount of times random sampling has to happen for the `bag` to be filled with a single value.

Comment: @Andrew Gustar I'm sure I could reduce the sample size considerably without compromising my results; I erred on the side of too big of a sample because the variance in the number of loops is very large, especially for larger values of c.

Comment: @d.b, epi99, Andrew Gustar: Thank you very much for your help. Like I said, I'm pretty new to this, and I really appreciate your feedback. This case aside, are you aware of a way to replace a while loop or repeat loop with a non-looping function? I do similar simulations a lot, and it would help to be able to improve my efficiency. Thanks again!

Comment: In this case the loop seems to be integral to the problem, so I'm not sure how it could be avoided.  If you were looking for the mean rather than the median, then there might be a neat probabilistic solution that does not involve simulation, so I suppose you could use small c to see if there is a predictable relationship between the mean and median.  Note that in the latest version of R (3.4.0) on-the-fly compilation is automatically done for looping functions, so that might speed things up if you are still on an older version.

Comment: @Alex Vornsand, vectorized functions - like the apply functions - iterate over a fixed length data structure - a list, a vector, a dataframe etc. In R, many loops can be eliminated this way. However, in this problem the number of repetitions isn't known.